# Is there any way to insert all relationships at once?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for a N:N relationship:

```
MyTable(IDTable1, IDTable2)
```

I have to collections with IDs, one collection with IDs from table 1 and another collection with IDs from table 2. I have to relation each id from collection 1 with all the IDs from collection 2.

Is it possible to do it with one T-Sql query or I need to create one T-Sql query for each relationship?

Thanks.

EDIT: I add the script to generate the 3 tables. Table01 with 3 rows, table02 with 6 rows and the N:N table with 6 records.

```
USE [Dummy01]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table01]    Script Date: 15/07/2018 16:43:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table01](
    [IDTable01] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tabl01] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDTable01] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship]    Script Date: 15/07/2018 16:43:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship](
    [IDTable01] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IDTable02] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table01_Table02_Relationship] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDTable01] ASC,
    [IDTable02] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table02]    Script Date: 15/07/2018 16:43:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table02](
    [IDTable02] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table02] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDTable02] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table01] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Table01] ([IDTable01], [Description]) VALUES (1, N'Description 01')
INSERT [dbo].[Table01] ([IDTable01], [Description]) VALUES (2, N'Description 02')
INSERT [dbo].[Table01] ([IDTable01], [Description]) VALUES (3, N'Description 03')
INSERT [dbo].[Table01] ([IDTable01], [Description]) VALUES (4, N'Description 04')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table01] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (2, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (2, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (2, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (3, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (3, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[Table01_Table02_Relationship] ([IDTable01], [IDTable02]) VALUES (3, 6)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (1, N'Description 01')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (2, N'Description 02')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (3, N'Description 03')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (4, N'Description 04')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (5, N'Description 05')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (6, N'Description 06')
INSERT [dbo].[Table02] ([IDTable02], [Description]) VALUES (7, N'Description 07')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table02] OFF
```

Comment: can you show some sample data with expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it with single query:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(IdTable1, IDTable2)
SELECT t1.IDTable1, t2.IDTable2
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
```

Comment: Does this way select the rows from table 1 and table 2 that I need to relation?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Based on your description `I have to relation each id from table 1 with all the IDs from table 2` it will work. So if you have table1 (1,2) and table2(3,4,5) you will get (1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)

Comment: You are right, I wanted to mean each ID in the collection 1 with all the IDs from the collection 2. The collection 1 has IDs from table 1 and collection 2 from table 2. But the collections don't have all IDs from each table.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Please create https://dbfiddle.uk with sample data and desired resultset.